# "Polish l" in bibliography using sharelatex

Tags: bibtex, sharelatex

I am using sharelatex with a separate bibliography file. Some of the authors cited use a lowercase Polish l in there name. The LaTeX code for this symbol is `\l{}`. Here is a typical entry:

```
 @article{123,
AUTHOR = {Karo\'{n}ski, Micha\l{} and \L{}uczak, Tomasz and Thomason, Andrew},...}
```

However, sharelatex keeps interpreting the \l{} as an incomplete math symbol (according to the compiler error) and is not producing proper output in my bibliography. Here is the compiler error:

```
<inserted text> 
                $
l.99 Alan Frieze and Micha\l
                            {} Karo\'nski.
I've inserted a begin-math/end-math symbol since I think
you left one out. Proceed, with fingers crossed.
```

BTW, `\L{}` and `\'{n}` both work just fine, along with all other foreign accents in names and titles in my bibliography, but the `\l{}` looks like `\ell` and everything after `\l{}` is in math mode.

Any ideas on work arounds out there?

Comment: It complies just fine on my desktop computer (I use TexShop on a Mac), but I am trying to work jointly with someone using sharelatex and I have never run into this sort of problem before.

Comment: Your project on ShareLaTeX has a refeinition of `\l` to `\ell` somewhere.

Comment: Unless you've somehow/somewhere redefined `\l` (and possibly `\L`), all you need to do is write `{\l}` and `{\L}` for BibTeX entries. The entire author field should read `AUTHOR = {Karo{\'n}ski, Micha{\l} and {\L}uczak, Tomasz and Thomason, Andrew},`.

Comment: I found this in my preamble: \renewcommand{\l}{\ell} Thanks for the help!